# FileSystemWatcher InternalBufferSize limit is getting exceeded

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

We are receiving files in FileSystemWatcher folder very frequently because of that InternalBufferSize limit is getting exceeded and files are being missed.
I am using the max limit 65536 allowed for InternalBufferSize.

I have also gone through many questions related to this, but could not find appropriate solution.

My Concern is:

1. Can we optimize this code more accurately?
2. If not, Is there any other way to watch the file?

   ```
    private void FileWatcher()   
        {
            try
            {
                f_Watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
                f_Watcher.Path = InFolder; 
                f_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                f_Watcher.Filter = "*.*";
                f_Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                f_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 
                f_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                f_Watcher.InternalBufferSize = 65536;
                f_Watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(LogBufferError);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            { throw; }
        }
   ```

OnChanged Method code block:

```
private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        InFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputPath"].ToString();
        DirectoryInfo getInDirectoryFile = new DirectoryInfo(InFolder);
        if (!getInDirectoryFile.Exists)
        {
            getInDirectoryFile.Create();
        }

        fileExt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileExt"].ToString();
        //string file_path = getInDirectoryFile.ToString();
        string file_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);

        string fname = e.Name.ToString();
        string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(file_path, fileExt); // GET ONLY .txt File
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {

            HLFile_Process.ProcessHL7File(file_path, fname); //Process HL7  files 
        }
        else
        {
            MIEventLogs.WriteLog("Currently there is no file at " + getInDirectoryFile + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() +
                                 "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" +
                                 DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" +
                                 DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MIEventLogs.WriteLog(ex.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" +
                             DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" +
                             DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

    }
    finally
    {
        MIEventLogs.WriteLog("MI File Process END: " + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" +
                             DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_" +
                             DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" +
                             DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code. This is just the setup for the watcher. That is interesting but rather secondary to the problem.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher has its limits. Is it an option to just not use it but poll the folder you need yourself for changes?

Comment: A generic advice is: Increasing the internal buffer is _not_ going to solve the problem (obviously). You need to make the event handler finish executing as quickly as possible.

Comment: What is `OnChanged` doing? As alternative you can maintain your internal queue (and post there in `OnChanged`) and process it in parallel.

Comment: A word of warning: NTFS starts getting noticeably slower if you have more than 80000 files in a folder. You might want to consider a different strategy for storing files if you need to keep more than 65000 in the same folder.

Comment: ... to pick up from above comment: If new files get created quicker than you can handle them, you"ll never have a chance and may want to consider a completely different solution. Otherwise: what I have done in the past was to create a DataFlow pipeline. And the FileSystemWatcher EventHandler simply enqueued filepaths there and that was all it did. That way I could mitigate all problem _I_ was having concerning the buffer. This will smoothen sudden peaks that would otherwise rip apart the buffer. But this will only shift the problem, if you cannot keep up downstream.

Comment: ^^ Now, I am not telling you, you _need to use a DataFlow pipeline_. Just anything that loads off concurrently and lets the event handler finish in close to no time will probably do.

Comment: @GuruStron OnChanged code is added to question, kindly take a look. and suggest solution.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I have posted all relevant code , Kindly take a look and suggest solution..

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` -> If you have this in an event handler, there is already something _fundamentally_ wrong.

Comment: 2. You know you can format a DateTime, right?

Comment: 3. Processing is executed blockingly. As I said: consider decoupling the processing from the event handling. Also: you access AppSettings over and over again. I think that could be cached and eventually drawn into the processing part and out of the event handling.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods As This was not my code, I now working on this code for now, So As you mentioned  real problem was System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); I commented this and now I was not getting  InternalBufferSize limit is getting exceeded error. Although Now sometime I am getting error file is being used by another process.  So I assumed whoever program is creating file, taking some microsecond to create file and mean while FileSystemWatcher is trying to process file, So I need to put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);. Now all things are working fine.

Comment: _"System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);"_ - That "works" only by chance. I'd suggest to enqueue the file into a queue that provides a certain retention time (maybe explore [Rx Extensions](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) as mentioned in Guru's answer or DataFlow) before exposing it for further process. The EventHandler itself should _never_ be blocked with a `Sleep`.

Comment: ^^ In fact, back when I had to deal with that, I'd debounce in that I'd enqueue the file indicated by the filesystemwatcher and only process it if the last change in size and change timestamp was older than x time (don't remember what the actual timespan was).

Comment: They even use it as an example : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ENLKa3 ...

Answer (score 3):

First of all remove the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);`. If you have a lot of events this only will lead to the problem you are facing - the internal buffer overflow. If you want to have some "grace" period (i.e. allow to upload more files) - introduce your custom queue and move the "wait" and processing to the dedicated worker(s). For example you can use the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-7.0), write to it in
the `OnChanged` and run few consumer `Tasks` which will consume the `ConcurrentQueue`, perform appropriate waits (`await Task.Delay` ...) and perform the work ('HLFile_Process.ProcessHL7File').

Also you can consider looking into [`Rx.NET`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) which can be appropriate for such handling, can throttle, batch and aggregate events.

Comment: @Ravi: ^^ this, PLUS: take a look into logging in general and "structured logging" in particular. It is not really directly related to the problem you are having, but the code snippet shows a lot of potential on that field.

Comment: _"If you want to have some "grace" period"_ - this may also cross your way as "debouncing".